# Click event doesn't work after append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I want to dynamic click on first click of paragraph but its not working.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".newclass").click(function() {
    var append_code = '<a href="google.com" class="hrefclick">Youre clicked</a>';
    $('body').append(append_code);
    $(".hrefclick").click();

    $(document).on('click', '.hrefclick', function(e) {
      alert("yess! You're clicked");
      // do whatever
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="newclass">
  Hit me!
</p>
```

[js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rushil_pachchigar/d8yn716t/9/)

Comment: Your code, which works fine, seems completely unrelated to the title which itself is unrelated to the description. What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: i want the alert to be called in just a single click not 2 clicks

Comment: So remove the inner `on()` event handler for the `.hrefclick` element

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).hrefclick is not a function getting error

Comment: you can make a jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to trigger the `click()` after the delegation, just change the order of your lines:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".newclass").click(function() {
    var append_code = '<a href="google.com" class="hrefclick">Youre clicked</a>';
    $('body').append(append_code);

    $(document).on('click', '.hrefclick', function(e) {
      alert("yess! You're clicked");
      // do whatever
    });
    $(".hrefclick").click();
    
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="newclass">
  Hit me!
</p>
```

Comment: Glad to help U @RushilPachchigar

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".newclass").click(function() {
    var append_code = '<a href="google.com" class="hrefclick">Youre clicked</a>';
    $('body').append(append_code);
    $(".hrefclick").click();

    $(document).on('click', '.hrefclick', function(e) {
      alert("yess! You're clicked");
      // do whatever
    });
    $('.hrefclick').trigger('click');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="newclass">
  Hit me!
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything correct except one thing - You are declaring event handler of your second click after the click itself. So, when second click is triggered, you don't have handler declared yet and you don't see any alert.
I rearranged it below. Trying running the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".newclass").click(function() {
    var append_code = '<a href="google.com" class="hrefclick">Youre clicked</a>';
    $('body').append(append_code);
      
      //on click event handler should be declared first before clicking
     $(document).on('click', '.hrefclick', function(e) {
      alert("yess! You're clicked");
      // do whatever
    });
    
    $(".hrefclick").click();

   
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="newclass">
  Hit me!
</p>
```